# Using subprocess to log out without sudo

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want my script to automatically log the current user out when the script has finished. It it to be ran on an Linux-based server (Ubuntu). I've tried this line of code, but it won't work.

```
subprocess.call(['logout'])
```

Gave the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I also tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'logout'])
```

But then the user'll have to enter his password to be logged out.  Without sudo on this one I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I do not want to run the script itself as root.

I want to be able to log a user directly out without them having to enter the password. When you use logout in a regular terminal you usually don't have to enter the password, so I don't really get why this is even an issue.

All help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have found a solution to my problem by adding a little extra code to ~/.bash_login (see my answer), but why what I'm trying above has not been answered.

Comment: Maybe you could run the script itself as sudo

Comment: Are you really sure it works with `sudo`? If I try `sudo logout`, I get told `sudo: logout: command not found`. I think `logout` is a shell builtin...

Comment: Try call(..., shell=True) so the command is evaluated as it was entered in shell

Comment: We need more information. What is the script doing? How is it being run? When is it being run? How is the user accessing the server?

Comment: Adding shell = True gives me the error "/bin/sh: 1: logout not found 127" I don't think the rest of the script is that relevant here as I'm not using this call as a part of anything, I just use it at the end when everything else is finished. It's used on one of my servers, and it's being ran when I log in. When it's finished, I don't want to manually log out again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I added

```
sys.exit(1)
```

To my script.

Then I added the following code to ~/.bash_login

```
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
    logout
fi
```

So the logout-command runs when the Python-script is finished.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, not sure if it does exactly what you need but it will logout the current user (not as cleanly as the you may like)

```
import os
os.system("pkill -KILL -u " + os.getlogin())
```

I have only tested this quickly but seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This will also kill anything running as said user. So if they have memory resident programs that they leave running even after they log off, this code will kill all of it.

Comment: @Drahkar ah thanks for explaining that. I did'nt think it was a very clean way to do so but couldn't think of another way to get the user logged out.

Answer (score 1):

With what you are trying to do, the best way to do so it probably to just wrap your python command in a Bash script that runs the python command and then ends with a logout.

logout is a Bash builtin function. It doesn't exist as a callable command you can use through Python.

Something to the effect of:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/script
./scriptname.py
logout
```

I can understand wanting to implement it all in Python. However you are going to run into issues if you work with any of the process of simply killing your session through a PID kill.

Comment: I did something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try killing your parent PID, which is likely to be the shell that started you - but that wouldn't help if you were then started by a script:

```
os.kill(os.getppid(),signal.SIGTERM)
```

However if you are replacing the shell, to act as the login program, you could alter the login setup to run your program, or `exec` from the parent shell, to replace it. Thus you wouldn't need to kill anything except yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Might this work for you?

```
cmd = 'logout'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

(I hadn't tried, just guessing!!)

Comment: `>>> cmd = 'logout'

>>> subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f3366b9db50>

>>> /bin/sh: 1: logout: not found`